# Upload a Pillow image to imgur in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, imgur

How do I upload a Pillow image to Imgur without downloading the image on to the computer? Is there a way? I'm using the [PyImgur API](https://github.com/Damgaard/PyImgur) to upload the image.

```
import pyimgur
import os    

my_image = Image.new("RGB", (50, 50), "white")

script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
file_dir = os.path.join(script_dir, "box.jpg")

my_image.save(file_dir)

CLIENT_ID = "1eis2d2qcz59mq73" # NOT MY REAL CLIENT ID.
im = pyimgur.Imgur(CLIENT_ID)
uploaded_image = im.upload_image(file_dir, title="My Image")
print(uploaded_image.link)    

os.remove(file_dir)
```

All I've got right now is a way to upload with a path from a directory on my computer. Is there any way to skip the downloading to the computer and just upload the image directly from PIL?

Thanks.

Comment: If the doc for pyimgur doesn't say anything about directly uploading a PIL image, it probably won't work. Look at [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html).

Comment: How would I write an image to a temp file?